# Use Turbodbc to connect to SQL Server, simple select

Tags: python, sql-server, turbodbc

I cannot get Python Turbodbc to connect to a Sql Server table, simple as that seems, to read or write user tables.  However I have established ODBC connection, and can print a list of objects from it.

## 1 List objects from server to test connection.  Seems to work:

```
from turbodbc import connect, make_options
options = make_options(prefer_unicode=True)
connection = connect(dsn='FPA', turbodbc_options=options)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo');''')
```

## 2 Simple Select: Does not work

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT * from [dbo].[Kits_Rec];''')
```

## From #1 I get

From # 2 message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.Kits_Rec'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe9MN.png)

Answer (score 0):

A SQL Server contains multiple databases, your dsn "FPA" probably doesn't specify the database name, so you are connecting to the master database instead of the database containing your Kits_Rec table.

Fix that dsn entry to specify the correct database, or use this syntax instead :

```
connection = connect(driver="MSSQL Driver",
                     server="hostname",
                     port="1433",
                     database="myDataBase",
                     uid="myUsername",
                     pwd="myPassword")
```

Comment: I tried the specs above, but since I am using an integrated windows connection, I could not populate the credentials info.  So I fixed the dsn, as you suggested, and that did the trick! I am very grateful, and a little embarrassed that never occured to me.   thank you